# Rails object update - check if any attribute is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I would like to be able to check if any of my object's attributes are nil when updating them so that I can display them to my users as a "draft" or "complete." Is there a way to check this? Or is there a better way of implementing functionality for this?

I have a bool attribute in the table called :complete. I'd like to change this to true or false, depending on it's state. Or, is there a way to check all attributes in the view for a nil attribute, and then remove the :complete attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if any of the object's attributes are `nil`, you can do

```
@object.attributes.values.include?(nil)
```

or

```
@object.attributes.values.any? &:nil?
```